# JavaScript prompt box: how to validate the cancel button (null)

Tags: javascript, validation, null, prompt

I have some JavaScript that is supposed to act as an example of how you can validate prompt box inputs.

User clicks button, enters a name, the JavaScript validates the input and displays an appropriate message. If the name is fine, it says it is a good name, if you enter a number/symbol it says invalid input (all good so far). However, when the user clicks "cancel" on the prompt box, the message displays "null" is a good name. I have tried to catch this but it doesn't seem to work. How can I make it display  a message saying you did not enter a valid name when the user clicks "cancel"?

Here is the JS fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/TurgidWizard/jzzsqu06/

html:

```
<button onclick="Validation()">Click Me</button>
<p id="vresult"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function Validation() {
    document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = "";
    PetName = prompt("Please enter your favourite pet's name:", "");
    var T = Test(PetName);
    if (T == false | T == "null") {
        document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = "You did not enter a valid name!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = PetName + " is a lovely name, good choice!!";
    }

}

function Test(str) {

    return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str)

}
```

Notice how I tried to use "if (T == false | T == "null")" to capture "null" ready for the invalid message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bad here:

```
if (T == false | T == "null")
```

`null` shouldn't be a string, or is `||` not `|`.

You also want to be checking if `PetName` is `null`, not the result of the regex.
The line should look like this:

```
if (!T || !PetName)
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzzsqu06/1/

Answer (score 0):

just check if `str` is `null` (as opposed to `"null"`)

```
function Test(str) {
    return (str !== null) && /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str);
}
```

then simply check

```
if (T === false) {
```

`prompt` will return the entered value if OK or return is pressed, including empty strings `""`, and `null` if Cancel is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating this line in your if condition deals with the cancel option:

```
if (T != '' && T != null){ 
 document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = "You did not enter a valid name!";
}
```